# Android: How to align switches' right boundaries?

Tags: android, xml

I have some switches that are listed vertically. But I don't know how to align them. I can align their right boundary manually on one device using contraints but when I changed a device, they are not aligned again.

[image: This is good result]

===================Below is bad result after changing device===============

[image: This is bad result]

So how can I achieve as the first image whatever device I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You would better use below properties for supporting better alignments in any device

        android:layout_alignStart="@id/aboveItem"
        android:layout_below="@id/aboveItem"

Example:
@+id/dispcount is already having absolute position which is First Item.
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnstart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/btnStart"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@id/dispcount"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/dispcount"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/btnStop"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnstart"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/btnstart"
         />


Above Example display vertically same alignment. Here example type is button, in your case its switch. xml attributes applies same for all alignments. take your own width & height.
```

By adding similar to your xml file, it will have auto adjustment for all the devices.

Comment: Thanks! But if I use your code only, they still cannot align. I found my problem was that the sizes of the switches were not same. After I adjusted the sizes and referred your code, it works!